# Setting cookie for request-url, when origin url and request url are different

Tags: node.js, http, cookies, request, cross-domain

Giving some code that I have tried so far.

> Request-origin - "abc.com", Request-url - "login.abc.com/login" (Post method)

```
function setCookie(req, res)
{
    //Some code goes here.
    //Code to set cookie
    res.cookie('test',"some value"); //This should set cookie for login.abc.com, which never happened
}
```

Also tried to set for domain

```
function setCookie(req, res)
{
    //Some code goes here.
    //Code to set cookie
    res.cookie('test',"some value",{domain:'.abc.com'},{'path' : '/'});//This should set cookie for .abc.com
}
```

***Following code is working as expected***

> Request-origin - "abc.com", Request-url - "abc.com/login" (Post method)

```
function setCookie(req, res)
{
    //Some code goes here.
    //Code to set cookie
    res.cookie('test',"some value",{domain:'.abc.com'},{'path' : '/'});//This set the cookie for .abc.com successfully
}
```

Can someone help me to understand why it is not setting cookie in the first case but it is setting cookie in the second case?

**NOTE** I am trying this in my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got the solution to my issue and able to achieve what I want. Writing this answer, so that some one else can get benifit in the future.

Changes in client side:-

```
$.ajax({type: "post",
        data: {},
        timeout: 30000,
        dataType:"json",
        xhrFields : {withCredentials : true} //Need to add this along with the request.
     })
```

Now server side changes:-

```
 var cors = require('cors');

app.post('/testRoute',
    cors({credentials:true,
    origin:'http://example.com'}), //Origin should be the url of the page, from where we are sending request.
  function(req, res){

     res.cookie('test',"some value",{'path' : '/'})
 })
```

Refer [cors-doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to know more about how to use `cors` in server side.

**NOTE:- Can not use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value as `*` if `xhrFields : {withCredentials : true}` we are specifying in the ajax request.**